# Firebase Storage - issue in running the android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on an android app that uses firebase storage. The app basically uses a few gestures out of which one is used to open the camera. The clicked photo is then saved to firebase storage. The app runs fine on my end and the clicked photo gets stored into firebase. But the issue is that one of my friends is working with me on this app and we are using the same gradle and android version and I have given her the owner rights for this project on firebase console, but despite that, the app on her device doesn't store the image on the firebase. In all, the app opens the camera on her device, the photo is clicked and then the app stops. Can anyone suggest a fix that is missing here???

logs:

```
06-14 21:26:12.868 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-14 21:26:13.057 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
06-14 21:26:13.059 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
06-14 21:26:13.093 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
06-14 21:26:13.199 16911-16954/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12451
06-14 21:26:13.199 16911-16954/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
06-14 21:26:13.200 16911-16954/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                 adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.arshi.auxilio
06-14 21:26:13.360 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.example.arshi.auxilio themeResourceId=2131362077
06-14 21:26:13.408 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-14 21:26:13.434 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
06-14 21:26:13.443 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
06-14 21:26:13.443 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
06-14 21:26:13.537 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/Activity: Activity.onPostResume() called 
06-14 21:26:13.537 16911-16954/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
06-14 21:26:13.551 16911-16981/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
06-14 21:26:13.553 16911-16981/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                       Build Date: 03/02/15 Mon
                                                                       Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1.2_RB1-AU017-20150302-1163306-1163307-1163308-1163309
                                                                       Remote Branch: 
                                                                       Local Patches: 
                                                                       Reconstruct Branch: 
06-14 21:26:13.555 16911-16981/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-14 21:26:13.572 16911-16981/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-14 21:26:13.583 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/Atlas: Validating map...
06-14 21:26:13.623 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/art: Thread[1,tid=16911,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x759b61f8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
06-14 21:26:13.634 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio E/MediaProfilesEx-JNI: register_com_lge_media_MediaProfilesEx
06-14 21:26:13.634 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio E/MediaRecorderEx-JNI: register_com_lge_media_MediaRecorderEx
06-14 21:26:13.634 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/AudioSystemEx: register_com_lge_media_LGAudioSystem
06-14 21:26:13.635 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio E/SurfaceControlEx: register_com_lge_view_SurfaceControlEx
06-14 21:26:13.636 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/art: Thread[1,tid=16911,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x759b61f8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
06-14 21:26:13.636 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/LGMtpDatabaseJNI: register_android_mtp_LGMtpDatabase
06-14 21:26:13.637 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/art: Thread[1,tid=16911,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x759b61f8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
06-14 21:26:13.638 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio D/LGMtpServerJNI: register_android_mtp_LGMtpServer
06-14 21:26:13.639 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/art: Thread[1,tid=16911,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x759b61f8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"
06-14 21:26:13.639 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio E/MediaPlayerEx-jni: register_com_lge_view_MediaPlayerEx
06-14 21:26:13.640 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/art: Thread[1,tid=16911,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb4827800,peer=0x759b61f8,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib/libhook_jni.so"

                                                                [ 06-14 21:26:13.640 16911:16911 D/         ]
                                                                register_com_lge_emoji_EmojiUtil
06-14 21:26:13.725 16911-16911/com.example.arshi.auxilio I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2d5a4469 time:103121285
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are sending the image to storage?? Or maybe the error your friend is getting? Logs?

Comment: Did you add your friend's debug certificate SHA1 to the Firebase project?

Comment: @CodeChimp yes I have added that!

Comment: @vivekverma there are no errors as such. It simply closes the app and no exception is thrown or anything is displayed.

Comment: I don't know if you are already doing it or not but try putting try catch around the function thats uploading the image. Sometimes the app crashes without showing the error in console but a try catch block should be able to catch it.